# How can I get model in GetDisplayWidgetRoute() method of my plugin?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I am working on Widget for my Category Pages in NopCommerce 2.80. In which I am using the Widget Zones to display the Specification Filters, Manufacturer and Price Filters.

My problem is I need the CategoryModel when ever my widget zone is called. But in this event I can't have the CategoryModel at this time. It's only available when I run the Category Action Method.

So how can I get my category model when my widget zone is called. Even I can do this by getting the Category Id and then retrieving all data from database. But I don't want to call the database to get this model values. It will create a performance issue.

How can I do this? Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible but I could be wrong.

However, you don't need to worry about performance issues if you retrieve the categoryModel again because it is being cached. The database will not be called again.